# Change background based on text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hanyb9da/

I want the page background to change to a background image that goes with the random quote displayed. The quotes work if I take out that changeBack function, as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/s43w7swb/2/).

What I did was create a for loop and tried to use jQuery to change the background depending on the quote in the array, but it didn't work.

Full js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var quotes = [
    "It's not the years, honey. It's the mileage.",
    "You see, in this world there's two kinds of people, my friend: Those with loaded guns and those who dig. You dig.",
    "I'll make him an offer he can't refuse.",
    "May the Force be with you.",
    "We buy things we don't need with money we don't have to impress people we don't like.",
    "Bond, James Bond.",
    "Heeere's Johnny!",
    "Hasta la vista, baby.",
    "Zed's dead, baby. Zed's dead."
  ];

  function getQuote() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);

  }

  $('#random-quote').click(function() {
    $('#main-quote').text(quotes[getQuote()]);
  });

  function changeBack() {
    var which = quotes.length;
    for (i = 0, i < which, i++) {
      if (which[i] === quotes[0]) {
        $("body").css("background-image", "url(https://images2.alphacoders.com/865/86520.jpg) no-repeat;");
      };
      else if (which[i] === quotes[1]) {
        $("body").css("background-image", "url(https://images3.alphacoders.com/238/238127.jpg) no-repeat;");
      };
      else if (which[i] === quotes[2]) {
        $("body").css("background-image", "url(http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1uqc0KVXXXXbsapXXq6xXFXXXC/Living-room-home-wall-decoration-fabric-poster-The-font-b-Godfather-b-font-font-b-movies.jpg) no-repeat;");
      };
      else if (which[i] === quotes[3]) {
        $("body").css("background-image", "url(https://stiggyblog.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/star-wars-a-new-hope-1977-factors-commercial-poster-by-hildebrandt.jpg) no-repeat;");
      };
      else if (which[i] === quotes[4]) {
        $("body").css("background-image", "url(http://wallpapercave.com/wp/oj4WPgT.png) no-repeat;");
      };
      else if (which[i] === quotes[5]) {
        $("body").css("background-image", "url(http://www.fotoloncho.com/fotos3/Revista%20Bond%201.jpg) no-repeat;");
      };
      else if (which[i] === quotes[6]) {
        $("body").css("background-image", "url(http://65.media.tumblr.com/ea930b76c8d84d9298910986efbb8082/tumblr_ngh0ohinb51rp2eyqo1_500.png) no-repeat;");
      };
      else if (which[i] === quotes[7]) {
        $("body").css("background-image", "url(http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/francois/mysterybox/terminator_1.jpg) no-repeat;");
      };
      else(which[i] === quotes[8]) {
        $("body").css("background-image", "url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-nIZXRMrbV5w/U5aannDQ7-I/AAAAAAAAMoQ/B81iFTid3rM/s1600/PULP+FICTION+-+UK+Poster+1.jpeg) no-repeat;");
      };


    };

  };

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't related to your problem, but `for (i = 0` is creating a global variable.

Comment: What should be the result of `which[i]`? `which` is a number (`var which = quotes.length;`) O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  

  $('#random-quote').click(function() {
    var quotes = [
{"quote": "It's not the years, honey. It's the mileage.", "background": "/images/bg1.jpg"},
{"quote": "Quote 2.", "background": "/images/bg2.jpg"},
{"quote": "Quote 3.", "background": "/images/bg3.jpg"}
];
    
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    var selectedQuote = quotes[ randomIndex ];

    $('#main-quote').text( selectedQuote.quote );
    var selectedBG = selectedQuote.background;
    console.log( selectedBG );
    // $("body").css("background-image", "url('"+selectedBG+"')");
  });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-quote"></div>
<button id="random-quote">Random Quote</button>
```

Comment: Why use two separate arrays?

Comment: [Tried it](https://jsfiddle.net/hanyb9da/10/), quotes work but the background doesn't change

Comment: @l-emi sorry, you need to use `url()` syntax for background image. I have updated the code.

Comment: @l-emi And here's your updated fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/hanyb9da/11/) that shows background change.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj ahh great it works!! thanks :) another question though -- how do I make the backgrounds not repeat? I know there's "no-repeat" in there somewhere

Comment: @l-emi For that you can simply add a rule in your css i.e. `body{background-repeat: no-repeat; }`.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do it like that... it's really heavy and you cannot change easily the order of your quotes... It would be better if your quotes array was an array of quotes objects. Each quote would have a text property and a class property like that :

```js
var quotes = [
  {text: "It's not the years, honey. It's the mileage.", className: "years"},
  {text: "May the Force be with you.", className: "starwars"}// etc...
];
```

After that you just have to change the classname of the element depending on the class of the quote. Then you manage the background images in a css file. Hope it helps.

EDIT: each time you want to add a new quote you'' just have to add a new quote in the array and a new css rule. It will be faster and easier to manage for you.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this :)

Answer (score 1):

dont use array of string. Instead use array of objects
like showen below

```
  var quotes = [
      {
          text:"It's not the years, honey. It's the mileage.",
          background: "url(https://images2.alphacoders.com/865/86520.jpg) no-repeat;"
      },
      {
          text:"You see, in this world there's two kinds of people, my friend: Those with loaded guns and those who dig. You dig.",
          background: "url(http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1uqc0KVXXXXbsapXXq6xXFXXXC/Living-room-home-wall-decoration-fabric-poster-The-font-b-Godfather-b-font-font-b-movies.jpg) no-repeat;"
      },
      {
          text:"May the Force be with you.",
          background: "url(http://wallpapercave.com/wp/oj4WPgT.png) no-repeat;"
      }
  ];
```

and here is the Fiddle. you can edit it to fullfil your needs

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/LoL4gn22/)

Comment: Image isn't changing in the fiddle

Comment: But it is console logged, means we get the value. play with that a little and you can do what you asked for